# problem with f.readline()?

Tags: python, file-io

I am reading one line at a time from a file, but at the end of each line it adds a `'\n'`.

Example:
The file has: `094 234  hii`
but my input is: `094 234  hii\n`

I want to read line by line but I don't need to keep the newlines...

My goal is to read a list from every line: I need `['094','234','hii']`,  not `['094','234','hii\n']`.

Any advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for line in f:
    words = line.split()
```

Answer (score 7):

1. It's not that it adds a `'\n'` so much as that there's really one there. Use `line = line.rstrip()` to get the line sans newline (or something similar to it depending on *exactly* what you need).
2. Don't use the `readline` method for reading a file line by line. Just use `for line in f:`. Files already iterate over their lines.

Answer (score 5):

The `\n` is not **added**, it's *part* of the line that's being read.  And when you do `line.split()` the traiing `\n` goes away anyway, so why are you worrying about it?!